# Only get single value from list executereader

Tags: c#, json, sql-server-2008, list, executereader

I am trying to read values form my database. But why am I getting only values with no column name?
this is my controller. that returns the values in JSON

```
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT State FROM MyDBtable";

            con.Open();
            List<string> StateList = new List<string>();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                StateList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                myTable = StateList
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and this is my JSON

```
{"myTable":["VA","CA"]}
```

Where as, it's suppose to give me

```
{"myTable":[{"State":"VA"},{"State":"CA"}]}
```

Why is it not reading and printing State

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code expecting the values, you'll quickly find out the wrong line and you will have a more concise problem. Of course, this example is still simple enough for us to figure out but in larger code it might not be so obvious.

Comment: Hi Tom.. i know it's reading the right data... my table as several columns.. and one of them is State... it has list of states like "VA", "CA"... what I am trying to do is read all the states that are on my table... which it is doing... but not printing the name of the column... I am guessing the way I have set up LIST array is not right

Comment: What I'm saying is that the debugger will show you that `StateList.Add(reader[0].ToString());` is adding just the state string and no longer the `State` property.

Comment: :) that is exactly my problem Tom... u put them in words for me... and like you said, I simplified the select statement to just one column... what I am working on has 7-8 columns and I am pretty sure tinkering with just on return Json will not solve my problem

Comment: No, I'm not saying you should solve this by yourself (if you can, great); but am just giving an example how debugging can help reveal the problem in general, such that you can say `StateList is a list of strings, I want it to be a list of properties, how do I do that?`. If you ever have a problem in much longer or harder code, that will definitely help us help you. Just an intermezzo, don't mind it... :)

Comment: I won't mind :)... juz a quick question... how would you use similar list that I have used to have properties as well(for 7-8 columns) and not just list of strings... or am I doing it right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are selecting state. This will create a new object where the `State` property is assigned the state, such that you get what you want:

```
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT State FROM MyDBtable";

con.Open();
List<string> StateList = new List<string>();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    StateList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
}

return Json(new
{
    myTable = StateList.Select(i => new { State = i })
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

For additional columns, see [lazyberezovsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13404621/47064) who has changed `StateList` to solve this.

Comment: Comments here have been removed. But for reference, there was an additional `;`.

Answer (score 4):

String does not have property "State". Create anonymous type instead:

```
myTable = StateList.Select(s => new { State = s })
```

**UPDATE:** Easiest solution for multiple columns - create a DTO for that

```
public class MyItem // of course use more descriptive name
{
   public string State { get; set; }
   public string Capital { get; set; }
   // etc
}
```

And fill it from reader:

```
List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    MyItem item = new MyItem();
    item.State = reader[0].ToString(); 
    item.Capital = reader[1].ToString(); 
    // etc
    items.Add(item);
}

return Json(new {  myTable = items }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

---

One more sample (with Dapper, which you can find on NuGet). Add `using Dapper;` to your code. Use same DTO class, as above.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    return Json(new {
       myTable = connection.Query<MyItem>("SELECT * FROM MyDBtable").ToList()
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @EagleFox when creating Json - replace `myTable = StateList` with this code

Comment: Thanks both ya'll... but m getting syntax error... I have made sure I have done what ya'll have said

Comment: guys... thanks to both of you... your answers work with one column data... but would it still be possible to use it with 7-8 columns??? for now I have marked this question as solved

Comment: Lazy.. Tom.. should I create another thread for multiple columns... let's say select statements like "SELECT STATE, CAPITAL, POPULATION, WEATHER FROM MYDBTABLE"... I am pretty sure it will be different to handle those all column names.

Comment: +1, seems you've got the game. @EagleFox: See his newest update.

Comment: sweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeet... thanks lazy... that one completely answers this question.... thanks to both ya'll for helping this poor soul

Comment: @TomWijsman I checked your other answers. Seems like this was just coincidence that our code was exactly same. Sorry. Removed all this flood. And removed downvote from you. Actually +1 even

Comment: @EagleFox consider also use some ORM (Linq2Sql, EF, Dapper) - it will do mapping for you without dealing with datareaders and other ado.net stuff

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Thanks, just wanted to get a point clear: Instead of commenting; just build up your answer over time instead of posting it altogether, that way you can rank up more votes over time (from later dupes / views / ...). If you are already at your daily cap, you could also just ignore it happening and go for additional answers on other questions. I might have a quite low reputation on SO (trying to change that!), but have almost 70k network wide so would be a shame if I did nothing but copy answers... Sorry for the hassle, I almost wanted to delete my answer and move on. :)

Comment: @lazy Thanks for the pointer... I am totally new to all this... will keep that in mind

Comment: @EagleFox *btw* don't forget to close SqlConnection. Tom, yep, but I'm not votes hunter :) That's why I spend my free time here after daily cap. Don't delete your answer! Its correct and accepted!

Comment: @EagleFox: I've been using EF for quite a while and it fits well in the whole LINQ world, I think LINQ2SQL is handy when you need to map to some existing database and I've seen Dapper as a good new improvement but haven't gotten that to work recently. The nice thing about those frameworks is that you can always jump back to SQL (or SqlBulkCopy for inserting) when you need performance, while being able to use much simpler code otherwise.

Comment: @lazy...dang... didn't know I was missing that con.Close();... rookie mistake.. my bad... :)

Comment: @Tom... yeah right now I am only using small databases... but as I climb up the ladder, will definitely try using link2sql/EF/Dapper